# How can I add a point or instance to points node with Python?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I want to create a geometry node tree in python, but for some types I get errors:

```
gnmod = obj.modifiers.new("My GeoNodes Modifier", "NODES")
bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_node_group_assign()
node_group = gnmod.node_group
nodes = node_group.nodes
nodePoint = nodes.new(type = 'Points') -> RuntimeError: Error: Node type Points undefined
nodePoint = nodes.new(type = 'POINTS') -> RuntimeError: Error: Node type POINTS undefined
```

How can I add a point node, or instance to points ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in the source code `release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/node_add_menu_geometry.py`:
`GeometryNodePoints` and `GeometryNodeInstanceOnPoints`